# Check expression string with Java bean using groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I need to check a string which will contains several expressions like for instance:

```
"phoneNumber == 334 && (data > 10 || name contains John)"
```

I want to match these properties to the one of a Java bean, for instance:

```
public class SubscriberProfile {

    private String name;

    private Integer phoneNumber;

    private Integer data;

    // getters and setters
}
```

For that I would like to use Groovy. 
My objective would be to check that the expression is using the beans' properties and that they don't violate the bean's rules (phoneNUmber is an Integer, name is a String, etc). The Groovy method will send false if the expression is not properly formatted.

But I'm new to Groovy and I'm kinda lost on how to implement this.

If someone could guide me to the right way it would be helpful!

Comment: why not using regex to validate your string pattern ?

Comment: Your question sounds like a too broad one. Have you tried solving it? Is there any particular problem you don't know how to solve? Otherwise it looks like you are asking for doing the homework for you.

Comment: Maybe it's too broad indeed, sorry. And no I don't want you to do everything, I just would like that you point me to the right direction because I'm confused.

 In fact I tried to use Groovyshell.evaluate method but it's not exactly what I want. 
I would like to find the Groovy method which can assert that the compared value on the right part (for instance ' 334 ' for expression ' phoneNumber == "334" ') match the type I assigned in the Java bean.
I hope it's more clear now :)

Comment: One way to go would be by running this as a groovy script with the profile as binding.  But the expression is just so close to groovy code (`John` vs `'John'`)